# Why does the universe like even numbers so much?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm not a math professional, so please forgive any incorrect assumptions here. Assuming we are working with whole numbers here. You may use other numbers if you wish to add to the thought.

When you add or subtract numbers, there needs to be an odd number of odd numbers for the result to odd. When you multiply numbers, all of the numbers must be odd to get an odd result. I know why those things happen (to a degree), but I am curious as to why such equations generally have a >75% (at least in the case of multiplication) of being even instead of odd. Is the universe oddist (racist against odd numbers)? If so, why is it?

Comment: Maybe the Universe is rather *nihilist* (loves zero). The only number stable under multiplication is $0$. This also holds modulo $n$ for any $n$, in particular for $n=2$.

Comment: Have you met my friends, the divisors?

Comment: All those things that have >75% chance of being even have >75% of being odd when 1 is added to them. So it balances out.

Comment: "When you add or subtract numbers, there needs to be an odd number of odd numbers for the result to odd."  And to be even it needs an even number of odds.  And evens have no significance.  So the odd and even sums are equally likely.

Comment: "When you multiply numbers, all of the numbers must be odd to get an odd result."  And all the numbers must be coprime to 3 to get a number indivisible by three.  And all the numbers must be coprime to 5 to get a number indivisible by 4.  If you have two numbers the prob. is 75 percent it is even but it's also a 5/9 prob a it is divisible by 3.  There is only a 9/25 prob it is divisible by 5 which is low but if there are 3 numbers then prob goes up to 61/125.  The probability of even products is simply because there are so many even numbers.

Comment: BrainStorm is so woke, he is revealing the sad reality that odd numbers still face in the Universe to this day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying is one way of throwing numbers into a sack and demand a single number that in a good way characterises all the numbers in the sack. It tells you exactly which prime numbers they are made up of. Now, if even one of the numbers in the sack is even, then the prime $2$ is included.

However, the is nothing special about $2$ in this regard, since the same thing can be said about $3$ or $5$ or $7$ or any other prime (or, indeed, any combination of primes, which is to say, any number at all). The only thing that makes $2$ special in this case is the psychological fascination with even numbers as opposed to, say, numbers divisible by $41$.

Comment: To add.  The only real significance of evens is there are so many of them so the prob of even has to be high.  If you have 5 numbers the prob of even is  31/32 which is high but the prob of being divisible by 3 is 87 percent which is also very high.  And its 2/3 for being divisible by 5 which is impressively high.  Its got an 56% chance of being divisible by 30 which should seem very unlikely, except... 2s,3s, and 5s, are reasonably common.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Hagen von Eitzen's excellent comment, consider the numbers which are divisible by $3$. If we take $a \times b$, we get:

- a number which is divisible by $3$ five times out of nine;
- a number which leaves remainder $1$ on division by $3$ two times out of nine;
- a number which leaves remainder $2$ on division by $3$ two times out of nine.

The universe loves to make numbers divisible by $3$, because numbers which are divisible by $3$ eat up all irregularities when you multiply.

Comment: Did you mean 2 on the third bullet point?

Comment: Yep, thanks! $\ \ $